# How to navigate iTunes with the Apple IR Remote

Tags: itunes

With the death of Front Row, I need an alternative 10' interface to iTunes.  My IR Remote will let me pause/play the current media, and of course the volume.  But I can't seem to navigate the library with nothing but the IR remote.

I know I can use the Remote software on an Touch / iPad, but it 10x the price of an IR remote, you're kidding right?

Comment: Not an answer, but you could install [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You could try an app like [Plex](http://www.plexapp.com/mac.php). It has a music component and is designed to be operated by a remote.

Comment: Perhaps I'm mistaken, but Plex looks like an ITunes alternative, which is not what I'm looking for.  I have all my media already tucked away in the iTunes Library, which FrontRow was aware of.

Comment: @Ralph It can connect to your iTunes library and play stuff from there

Answer (score 0):

I just want to tell you that you don't have to miss Front row at least for now, because as far as I know you still can run Front row with Lion by copying these files from your Snow Leopard to Lion

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Front Row.app
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackRow.framework
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iPhotoAccess.framework
/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.RemoteUI.plist
/Applications/Front Row.app
```

Please refer the following links for more info.

http://www.mac-hatter.com/blog/frontrowenablerforlion

http://www.tuaw.com/2011/07/21/how-to-install-front-row-on-lion/

Comment: Apparently not after updating to iTunes 10.4, but thanks.